# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Layover Legend

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-2013

So I am trying to add a legend of the calendar layover colors like in the picture below as a webpart in SharePoint 2013. The calendar webpart is on the home page but the color coded layovers do not make any sense without a legend showing what each color means. So is there a webpart that will allow me to do something like in the image below? Thanks for any help you can provide.
[image]

Comment: How often do you expect the legend (appears to be a status or category of some sort) to change? If rarely or never it's probably quickest to just create something like the below in raw HTML and display it via Content Editor web part.

Comment: @Stevangelista Yeah it shouldn't need to change much. If anything just the colors will change based on client preference but that is super simple for me to manage in the html. Great approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If static HTML will do, you can do something like this:

```css
#legend, img {
  width:100%;
}
.legendItem {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:left;
}
.label {
  color:white;
  padding-left:5px;
}
.onboarding {
  background-color:green
}
.pending {
  background-color:purple
}
.offboarding {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wlZdaCZ.png">
<div id="legend">
  <div class="legendItem onboarding"><span class="label">Onboarding</span></div>
  <div class="legendItem pending"><span class="label">Pending Approval</span></div>
  <div class="legendItem offboarding"><span class="label">Offboarding</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also just thought about using a simple content editor web part, adding a table to it, then just edit the table html. I'll try your approach as well. Thanks again!